# JAVASCRIPT Fetch JSON from PATH returns GET 404 on FLASK Web App

Tags: javascript, json, flask, http-status-code-404

So on my Flask Web App I'm having this issue of getting 404 when accessing JSON file on the static folder of the FLASK.

Here is my directory:

Parent folder -> static -> js -> script.js

Parent folder -> static -> JSON_folder -> data.json

Parent folder -> templates -> index.html

So basically I'm trying to fetch the data from the data.json file on the script.js. On the code shown below unfortunately returns a GET 404

```
fetch('../saved_json/data.json')
.then(function(response){
    return response.json();
}).then(function(detections){
   console.log("test");
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a flask error. But I tried everything in terms of file routing and something doesn't work.

Comment: Correction:
    Parent folder -> static -> saved_json -> data.json

Comment: [Edit] to show  relevant flask  code as [mcve]. You can also show output of `tree` to better visualize the  folder structure.